# How to prove that multiplying the equation $Ax = B$ from the left with invertible matrices doesn't change set of solutions of the given system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

> How to prove that multiplying the equation $Ax = B$ from the left with
>   invertible matrices doesn't change set of solutions of the given
>   system ?

In the book of *Linear Algebra in Action by Harry Dym*, at page 21, it is given the above statement, and I don't know which actions would change the set of solution of the given system, so I basically stuck.

Comment: To get started, it would help to give your invertible matrix a name. Let's call it $M$. Your goal is to show that the set of all solutions to $Ax=b$ is equal to the set of all solutions to $MAx=Mb$.

Comment: @littleO Thanks for your comment, but the problem starts after that step.

Comment: Why not to multiply both sides just by $M^{-1}$. If $M$ is invertible it can be done and this leads directly to $Ax=B$..

Comment: @Widawensen I didn't get what your algorithm is after multiplying both side with $M^{-1}$

Comment: A basic strategy for showing that two sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ are equal​ is to first show that $S_1 \subset S_2$ and then show that $S_2 \subset S_1$. So let $S_1$ be the set of all solutions to $Ax=b$, and let $S_2$ be the set of all solutions to $MAx = Mb$. Can you show that $S_1 \subset S_2$?

Comment: $M^{-1}(MAx)=M^{-1}(MB)$

Comment: Every invertible matrix is the finite product of elementary matrices. Each elementary row operation is represented by such an elementary matrix.

Comment: @littleO Yes I can, thanks a lot,  but if $M$ is not invertible, then why this is not the case ? I mean where did we use the fact that $M$ is invertible ?

Comment: We are not done yet. We still have to show that $S_2 \subset S_1$. Can you do that?

Comment: @Fakemistake Then, can you prove your own statement ?

Comment: @littleO Let $e \in S_2$, then $Ae  = M^{-1}MB = B $.

Comment: @littleO If you post your comments as an answer, I will accept it.Thanks again by the way :)

Comment: My comment relates to your statement after Widawensens first comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We discussed a proof already in the comments, so I'll post an answer.  Most people would just write something like this: Suppose $M$ is invertible.  Then
$$
Ax = b \implies MAx = Mb \implies M^{-1} MAx = M^{-1} M b \implies Ax = b. \text{QED}.
$$

---

But I'll also write out a proof in more detail. We are given an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ and an $m \times 1$ column vector $b$.  We want to show that if $M$ is an invertible $m \times m$ matrix, then the set of all solutions to $Ax = b$ is equal to the set of all solutions to $MAx = Mb$.

So, let $S_1 = \{ x \mid Ax = b \}$ and let $S_2 = \{ x \mid MAx = Mb \}$.
We'll show that $S_1 \subset S_2$ and also that $S_2 \subset S_1$, which will prove that $S_1 = S_2$.

First, let's show that $S_1 \subset S_2$.  If $x \in S_1$, then $Ax = b$, so multiplying by $M$ we find that $MAx = Mb$.  This shows that $x \in S_2$.  So, $S_1 \subset S_2$.

Next, we'll show that $S_2 \subset S_1$. If $x \in S_2$, then $MA x = Mb$.  Multiplying by $M^{-1}$, we find that $M^{-1} MAx = M^{-1} Mb$, which implies that $Ax = b$.  This shows that $x \in S_1$. So, $S_2 \subset S_1$. This completes the proof that $S_1 = S_2$.